# bug: Unable to handle kernal null pointer difference at 0000000000000068

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

Ubuntu installation on my laptop shows a big message starting with above one. Have to restart to connect to the internet

Comment: We would need a lot more information to help you , hardware, what you do to trigger the crash, debugging info, etc. You are far better off filing a bug report as you are unlikely to write a kernel module even if we told you how to do so. Also, custom kernels are unsupported ;)

Comment: I just surf the web with a 3G dongle and got this message. The dongle is disconnected always when I get this. I have to restart to use it normally. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0char6qms86mhxd/IMG_20141221_230134625.jpg?dl=0